# Oracle SQL Subtracting Results From Similar Line Items

Tags: sql, oracle

I have built my query so that, so far, it shows the following data:

```
ORDERNUM  PARTNO  ORDERQTY  USEQTY
1112      0144    1         2
1113      0144    1         2
1114      0144    1         2
1115      0144    1         2
```

What I need to do now is figure out how to manipulate the USEQTY column, or make a new column, that sequentially subtracts from the initial value. There common link between all these line items in the PARTNO. The USEQTY column cannot ever be greater than the ORDERQTY column, and for each sequential ORDERNUM, the ORDERQTY should be subtracted from the USE QTY. Below is how the table should look:

```
ORDERNUM  PARTNO  ORDERQTY  USEQTY
1112      0144    1         1
1113      0144    1         1
1114      0144    1         0
1115      0144    1         0
```

Should I be doing a partition or something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with
     test_data ( ordernum, partno, orderqty, useqty ) as (
       select 1112, 0144, 1, 2 from dual union all
       select 1113, 0144, 1, 2 from dual union all
       select 1114, 0144, 1, 2 from dual union all
       select 1115, 0144, 1, 2 from dual
     )
--  end of test data; solution (SQL query) begins below this line
select ordernum, partno, orderqty,
       greatest(useqty - coalesce(sum(orderqty) 
                                  over (partition by partno order by ordernum
                                  rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
                                  , 0)
                , 0) as useqty
from test_data
order by partno, ordernum  -- if needed
;

  ORDERNUM     PARTNO   ORDERQTY     USEQTY
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      1112        144          1          2
      1113        144          1          1
      1114        144          1          0
      1115        144          1          0

4 rows selected.
```

With that said, this can probably be done more efficiently if you go back a step or two (do NOT use what you show in the original post as an intermediate step). The USEQTY column in particular shouldn't be an "input" to this query; the initial amount or quantity should be used directly, whatever its source.

Comment: Understand about going back a step to do this. I certainly will. Just had no idea where I begin. I use a running sum over usage records to get the USEQTY until its either equal to or just greater than the ORDERQTY. The value of 2 thats in USEQTY is the result of that running sum.

Comment: This was the correct answer for the question I asked, but it turns out you were right about going into the sub queries. It looks like my problem should be solved in a different way.